# EnsureUser using email address in SharePoint client object model

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, csom

I need to update a FieldUserValue field in sharepoint 2013. i am only given an email address data. I can't user EnsureUser since it only accepts the logonName. i used the FromUser method but it gives me an error that says "the user does not exist or is not unique"

```
FieldUserValue user = FieldUserValue.FromUser(email);
```

it worked when i tried using my email address but when i use the email addresses in my data it results in an error. how do i fix the issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could resolve user by email address using [Utility.ResolvePrincipal method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.utilities.utility.resolveprincipal.aspx), for example:

```
var result = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.Utility.ResolvePrincipal(ctx, ctx.Web, emailAddress,Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.PrincipalType.User,Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.PrincipalSource.All, null, true);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
if (result != null)
{
    var user = ctx.Web.EnsureUser(result.Value.LoginName);
    ctx.Load(user);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();    
}
```

**References**

[Get user identity and properties in SharePoint 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163913.aspx)

Comment: there aren't many examples like this for resolving User with just email id in the web. thank you @Vadim